# saml2 identity provider in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, saml, simplesamlphp

I must implement and integrate a SAML2 Identity Provider (IdP) with an existing Symfony 2 application.

I found some bundle that implement Service Provider (SP) but not Identity Provider so I think that I may use [SimpleSAMLphp library](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp). Are there other solutions?

How can I integrate my user provider logic with SimpleSAMLphp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As Milos Tomic mentioned in his comment, aerialship/lightsaml is replaced by [lightsaml/sp-bundle](https://github.com/lightSAML/SpBundle). You can find an [introduction here](https://www.lightsaml.com/SP-Bundle/).

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I have recently set up a SAML Solution using [Simplesamlphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) as IDP and [SamlSPBundle](https://github.com/aerialship/SamlSPBundle/) as SP and everything is working well.

I recommend installing Simplesamlphp first, following this [good Documentation here](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp).

Once you have the IDP up and running, you should see a Welcome page and a Tab called Federation (or something like that, my Installation is in german). There you should see one option "SAML 2.0 IdP Metadata". Follow that link and copy the XML shown to a seperate file and save that file.

On the symfony side, I created a new Bundle and called that "SamlBundle". Download and install SamlSPBundle as described in their Documentation (Step 1 and Step 2).

Create your SSO State/User class (Step 3). Here is an example how I did it:

```
namespace SamlBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="samlUser")
 */
class SamlUser extends \AerialShip\SamlSPBundle\Entity\SSOStateEntity implements UserInterface
{

/**
 * initialize User object and generates salt for password
 */
public function __construct()
{
    if (!$this->userData instanceof UserData) {
        $this->userData  = new UserData();
    }
    $this->setRoles('ROLE_USER');
}

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string username
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * @var string targetedId
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true, name="targeted_id")
 */
protected $targetedID;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, name="provider_id", nullable=true)
 */
protected $providerID;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, name="auth_svc_name")
 */
protected $authenticationServiceName;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, name="session_index", nullable=true)
 */
protected $sessionIndex;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, name="name_id")
 */
protected $nameID;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, name="name_id_format")
 */
protected $nameIDFormat;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="created_on")
 */
protected $createdOn;

/**
 * @var UserData
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserData", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_data", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $userData;
```

Add your class to config.yml (Step 4):

```
# app/config/config.yml
aerial_ship_saml_sp:
    driver: orm
    sso_state_entity_class: SamlBundle\Entity\SamlUser
```

Update your security.yml (Step 5). Example;

```
providers:
    saml_user_provider:
        id: SamlToState

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    saml:
        pattern: ^/(?!login_check)
        anonymous: true
        aerial_ship_saml_sp:
            login_path: /saml/sp/login
            check_path: /saml/sp/acs
            logout_path: /saml/sp/logout
            failure_path: /saml/sp/failure
            metadata_path: /saml/sp/FederationMetadata.xml
            discovery_path: /saml/sp/discovery
            local_logout_path: /logout
            provider: saml_user_provider
            create_user_if_not_exists: true
            services:
                openidp:
                    idp:
                        #the XML-File you saved from the IDP earlier
                        file: "@SamlBundle/Resources/idp-FederationMetadata.xml"
                    sp:
                        config:
                            # required, has to match entity id from IDP XML
                            entity_id: http://your-idp-domain.com
                            # if different then url being used in request
                            # used for construction of assertion consumer and logout urls in SP entity descriptor
                            base_url: http://your-sp-domain.com
                        signing:
                             #self signed certificate, see [SamlSPBundle docs][4]
                            cert_file: "@SamlBundle/Resources/saml.crt"
                            key_file: "@SamlBundle/Resources/saml.pem"
                            key_pass: ""
                        meta:
                            # must implement SpMetaProviderInterface
                            # id: my.sp.provider.service.id

                            # or use builtin SpMetaConfigProvider
                            # any valid saml name id format or shortcuts: persistent or transient
                            name_id_format: transient
                            binding:
                                # any saml binding or shortcuts: post or redirect
                                authn_request: redirect
                                logout_request: redirect
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
            invalidate_session: true
```

Next import the routes as described in Step 6. Before you go on to Step 7, I recommend to create your User provider class first. Here is an example:

```php
namespace SamlBundle\Models;

use SamlBundle\Entity\SamlUser;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use AerialShip\SamlSPBundle\Bridge\SamlSpInfo;
use AerialShip\SamlSPBundle\Security\Core\User\UserManagerInterface as UserManagerInterface;


class SamlToState implements UserManagerInterface
{
/**
 * @var ContainerInterface   base bundle container
 */
public $container;

/**
 * Constructor with DependencyInjection params.
 *
 * @param \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container
 */
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)  {
    $this->container = $container;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function loadUserBySamlInfo(SamlSpInfo $samlInfo)
{
    $user = $this->loadUserByTargetedID($samlInfo->getAttributes()['eduPersonTargetedID']->getFirstValue());

    return $user;
}

private function loadUserByTargetedID($targetedID) {
    $repository = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getRepository('MrmPosSamlBundle:SamlUser');

    $user = $repository->findOneBy(
            array('targetedID' => $targetedID)
    );

    if ($user) {
        return $user;
    }

    throw new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException();
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function createUserFromSamlInfo(SamlSpInfo $samlInfo)
{
    $repository = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getRepository('MrmPosSamlBundle:SamlUser');

    $user = $repository->findOneBy(
            array('nameID' => $samlInfo->getNameID()->getValue())
    );

    if ($user) {
        $user->setUsername($samlInfo->getAttributes()['eduPersonPrincipalName']->getFirstValue());
        $user->setTargetedID($samlInfo->getAttributes()['eduPersonTargetedID']->getFirstValue());
        $user->setRoles($samlInfo->getAttributes()['role']->getFirstValue());
    } else {
        $user = new SamlUser();
        $user->setUsername($samlInfo->getAttributes()['eduPersonPrincipalName']->getFirstValue());
        $user->setTargetedID($samlInfo->getAttributes()['eduPersonTargetedID']->getFirstValue());
        $user->setRoles($samlInfo->getAttributes()['role']->getFirstValue());
        $user->setSessionIndex($samlInfo->getAuthnStatement()->getSessionIndex());

        $user->setProviderID($samlInfo->getNameID()->getSPProvidedID());
        $user->setAuthenticationServiceName($samlInfo->getAuthenticationServiceID());
        $user->setNameID($samlInfo->getNameID()->getValue());
        $user->setNameIDFormat($samlInfo->getNameID()->getFormat());
    }

    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return $user;
}

public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $repository = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getRepository('MrmPosSamlBundle:SamlUser');

    $user = $repository->findOneBy(
            array('username' => $username)
    );

    if ($user) {
        return $user;
    }

    throw new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException();
    return false;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    $repository = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getRepository('MrmPosSamlBundle:SamlUser');

    $newUser = $repository->findOneBy(
            array('nameID' => $user->getNameID())
    );

    if (!$newUser) {
        throw new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException();
    }

    return $newUser;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return true;
}

}
```

Create your service in SamlBundle/Resources/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    SamlToState:
        class: SamlBundle\Models\SamlToState
        arguments: [@service_container]
```

Now its time for Step 7, exchanging Metadata. get the SP XML as described and go back to your IDP. You find a "XML to simpleSAMLphp Metadata converter" Link on the Federation Tab. Follow that link and convert your SP XML Data to the simpleSAMLphp format. Add that data to the saml20-sp-remote.php file in your IDPs metadata folder.

Ok, I'm pretty sure that I forgot something, but hopefully this information helps. If you get stuck, your welcome to get back to me.

Comment: Great for SP bundle solutions! 
But about IdP with SimpleSAMLphp, how to integrate my symfony user provider? Now I have enable "sqlauth:SQL" in config/authsource.php with my custom raw SQL query to provide user data...

Comment: In my project I have some kind of redundency, meaning there is a table containing user data on the IDP and the SP. The IDP handles authentication, the SP authorisation.As a user can have different privileges lets say on Site A and Site B, the IDP just tells you, that the User has successfully logged in. All other things are handled by the SP.

Comment: Note that aerialship/lightsaml is replaced with https://packagist.org/packages/lightsaml/lightsaml

Answer (score 1):

I found:

1. [SURFnet SamlBundle](https://github.com/SURFnet/Stepup-saml-bundle) that is a simple symfony2 wrapper of the library you found.
2. [SamlSpBundle](https://github.com/aerialship/SamlSPBundle) more used and well documented.

Take a look at this two. The first is very simple and i don't know if is sufficient documented, of course is an active project. The second seem more powerful and documented but can be more difficult to configure.

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you. The second one implements only SP functionality, I will try first.

Comment: ok! good luck! Let me know how complicated is the integration of this bundle!

Comment: @AlessandroPessina: did you try out the SURFnet SamlBundle to create an IDP? If so, how difficult was it? The documentation looks very sparse.